# How do i access a variable inside a while loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I am trying to access question 2 in the the second while loop, but i can't since it is in a block scope in the first while loop. I tired declaring it outside of the while loop but then the while loop will not work.  Any help is appreciated. The if statement in the second while loop will not work because question 2 is in  a block scope.

```
var readlineSync = require("readline-sync");

function run() {
  var question1 = readlineSync.question("Press any key to start the game");

  const randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  const randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

  /*first placement*/
  firststring(1);
  function firststring(stringlength) {
    var emptyString1 = "";
    var emptyString2 = "";
    var characters = "ABC";
    var characters2 = "ABC";
    let operation1 = false;
    let operation2 = false;

    for (var i, i = 0; i < stringlength; i++) {
      emptyString1 += characters.charAt(
        Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)
      );
    }
    for (var i, i = 0; i < stringlength; i++) {
      emptyString2 += characters.charAt(
        Math.floor(Math.random() * characters2.length)
      );
    }
    var totalOne = emptyString1 + randomNumber1;
    var totalTwo = emptyString2 + randomNumber2;
    var toString1 = totalOne.toString();
    var toString2 = totalTwo.toString();
    console.log(toString1);
    console.log(toString2);

    if (toString1 === toString2 || totalOne === totalTwo) {
      run();
    }

    let question2;

    while (!operation1) {
      question2 = readlineSync.question('Enter a location to strike ie "A2"');

      if (question2 === toString1 || question2 === toString2) {
        operation1 = true;
        console.log("Hit. You have sunk a battleship. 1 ship remaining.");

        break;
      } else {
        console.log("You have missed!");
      }
    }

    let question3;
    let question4;


    while (!operation2) {
      question3 = readlineSync.question("Enter a location to strike the second battleship")

        if (question3 === toString1 || question3 === toString2) {
          operation2= true;
          console.log('HIT!')
           break;
        } else {
          console.log('You have misssed')
        }


        if (question3 === question2) {
          console.log("You have already entered that value.");
        }
      }
      
              question4 = readlineSync.question(
                "You have destroyed all battleships. Would you like to play again? Y/N"
              );
          
      
      
            if(question4 === "Y" || question4 === "y") {
              run();
            }
    }

}
run();
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you copy the value of the question2 in another variable with the scope you want no ?

Comment: what variable? it is already in the while loop. I don't think that would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code above, `question2` is declared and available for the whole `firststring` function, that and is available to both while loops.

`let` in JavaScript defines a variable for its current scope and anything below like so:

```
let a;
let b = 3;
if (true) {
  console.log(b); // 3
  let c = 5;
  b = 4;
  a = 6;
}
console.log(a); // 6
console.log(b); // 4
// console.log(c); // Uncaught ReferenceError: c is not defined
```

EDIT:
With the example result provided, the problem is that the `if (question3 === question2)` check is called after the "hit check" (which breaks the loop). You need this:

```
while (!operation2) {
  question3 = readlineSync.question("Enter a location to strike the second battleship")
  if (question3 === question2) {
    console.log("You have already entered that value.");
  } else if (question3 === toString1 || question3 === toString2) {
    operation2= true;
    console.log('HIT!')
    break;
  } else {
    console.log('You have misssed')
  }
}
```

Comment: but when i run the code i dont get the value of question 2. Because the value is STUCK in question 2. Try running the code and then adding the value of question2 in the second while loop.

Comment: OH, looking at your image, the problem isn't accessing question2 but that it is in the wrong spot.